# Automatically re-initialize VBA global variables after a run-time error

Tags: vba, variables, error-handling, initialization, global

Question #1: Does `Public myGobalVar As Integer` need to be re-defined when a run-time error occurs?

Question #2: How do I automatically re-initialize my gobal variables whenever a run-time error occurs in the code?

Question #3: Would this error handling routine fail when dealing with unforeseen scenarios? How do I make it more fool-proof or robust?

Please refer to the pseudo code below.

```
''' Question #1: Does Public myGobalVar As Integer need to be re-defined when a run-time error occurs?
Public myGobalVar As Integer

Sub Application_Startup()
    Call InitializeGobalVar()
End Sub

Sub InitializeGobalVar()
    myGobalVar = 3
End Sub

Sub One_in_many_mySubs()
On Error Goto ErrHandler_myGobalVar
    Dim objApp as Outlook.Application
    Set objApp as Application

    msgbox myGlobalVar

    ' erroneous event may occur somewhere in the code

    Err.Clear
    ' skip ErrHandler_myGobalVar and exit sub after set objApp = Nothing

ErrHandler_myGobalVar:
    if Err.number <> 0 then

    ''' Question #2: How do I automatically restart InitializeGobalVar whenever a run-time error occurs in the code?
        Call InitializeGobalVar

        MsgBox Err.Description
    end if

    Set objApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to reinitialise a global variable if the error transfers you to an error handling routine.  So questions 1 and 2 are answered.   Err.clear should probably be in your error handling routine.  If you adequately resolve your error  in the error handing routine then resume next will continue from the line after the error without losing the value of your global variable otherwise exit the error handling procedure after cleaning up and setting on error goto 0.  Your global variable will still be valid.

Comment: If global variables can't be revitalized upon error, then the question really asks, does my error handling code "adaquately resolve" unforeseen errors, such that global variable will be kept alive all the time (Question #3). To this you have suggested putting [on error goto 0] into the code. However, error scenarios are difficult to track and not easily replicated, making it unobvious for me to decide where to place them codes. Please kindly provide code if possible.

Comment: Global variables are not lost until VBA gives up and stops. i.e if you select end when you get an error dialog.  So whilst you an in your error handling code your global variables are still valid.  On error goto 0 merely hands back error reporting to VBA.  This is not the place for detailed discussion so II'd politely suggest you need to do a bit more research on handling errors.  This would be a good place to start  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement